# how can webpack hash existing classes in a static html site?

Tags: webpack, css-loader

I'm trying to update some very old websites I made years ago to run on webpack. I also discovered a feature that can hash the classnames using css-loader, but it does not seem to apply to my project. Maybe it only works with linked styles.

#### index.html

```
<html><div class="hashThis"></div></html>
```

#### index.js

```
require("../static/css/index.css")
require("../static/css/unsemantic-grid-responsive.css")

$(async () => { 
...
```

#### webpack.config.js

````
process.env.mode || require('dotenv').config()

const HtmlWebpackPlugin     = require('html-webpack-plugin')
const WebpackObfuscator = require('webpack-obfuscator')
const { EnvironmentPlugin } = require('webpack')

console.log('[-] webpack - webpack.config.js -', process.env.mode, process.env.srv_host, process.env.srv_port)

module.exports = {

    mode: process.env.mode,

    devServer: {

        client: { overlay: false },
        
        hot: process.env.mode === 'development',

        liveReload: process.env.mode === 'development',

        static: {

            directory: './static', publicPath: '/',
            serveIndex: process.env.mode === 'development',
        },

        proxy: {},

        port: process.env.srv_port,

        host: process.env.srv_host,

        // proxy: { '/api': { target: process.env.api_host, pathRewrite: { '^/api': '' } } },
    },

    entry: './src/index.js',

    plugins: [

        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({ template: './static/index.html' }),

        new EnvironmentPlugin(['api_host']),

        new WebpackObfuscator ({ rotateStringArray: true })
    ],

    output: {},

    module: {

        rules: [ { 
            
            test: /\.css$/i, 
            use: [
                { loader: 'style-loader' },
                { loader: 'css-loader', options: { modules: { localIdentName: '[sha1:hash:hex:4]' } }}, //  importLoaders: 1, 
            ]
        }],
    }
}```
````